# How can I tell if a encrypted (LUKS) device is already open?

Tags: encryption, luks, block-device, device-mapper

Is there a way to tell, given a path to a LUKS block device, and not knowing the passphrase, whether the device is already open (decrypted)?

What about knowing the path to the decrypted device?

Comment: This does not answer the respective question, but If you only know the device mapper name (which you would supply to `cryptsetup luksClose` for example) the return value of `dmsetup status <device>` indicates if it is open.

Answer (score 3):

The following code checks whether the device DEV_LUKS is an encrypted LUKS device and already opend (decrypted).

```
DEV_LUKS=/dev/sda

cryptsetup isLuks $DEV_LUKS && echo "$DEV_LUKS is a LUKS Device" || echo "$DEV_LUKS is not a LUKS Device"
test -b /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-*$(cryptsetup luksUUID $DEV_LUKS | tr -d -)* && echo "$DEV_LUKS is opened" || echo "$DEV_LUKS is not opened"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple option which may show what you need:

```
dmsetup ls | grep crypt | cut -f1 -d_
```

On my system this returns:

```
sda5
```

This returns device names which include crypt which may be the case in your system.