# How to check if a LUKS device is unlocked, without sudo permissions?

Tags: encryption, luks, block-device, device-mapper

Is there any way to check if a LUKS device is unlocked, without having sudo permissions?

I'm aware of [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296583/how-can-i-tell-if-a-encrypted-luks-device-is-already-open) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343127/how-to-find-out-whether-a-luks-encrypted-partition-is-opened-of-closed/343163#343163), but all the answers require sudo.

It seems that I've found an indirect way (processing the `CleartextDevice` value of `udisksctl info`'s output), but even assuming it's a stable solution, it's a hack at best.

Gnome-disks, for example, doesn't require sudo permissions, but it still decodes the locked/unlocked status of LUKS devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Gnome-disks, for example, doesn't require sudo permissions, but it still decodes the locked/unlocked status of LUKS devices.

GNOME Disks uses UDisks to get the information. There's nothing hacky about it, the `CleartextDevice` property will be always either `/` if the device is locked or a valid object path in form of `/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d<num>`, where `dm_2d<num>` translates to `dm-<num>`, the device mapper cleartext device name (`-` is encoded as `_2d` on DBus). If you don't want to parse `udisksctl` output, you can use `busctl` to get only the `CleartextDevice` property. It can also format the output in JSON for simpler parsing.

Locked LUKS device:

```
$ busctl get-property org.freedesktop.UDisks2 /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda1 org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Encrypted CleartextDevice -j
{
        "type" : "o",
        "data" : "/"
}
```

Unlocked LUKS device:

```
$ busctl get-property org.freedesktop.UDisks2 /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/nvme0n1p3 org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Encrypted CleartextDevice -j
{
        "type" : "o",
        "data" : "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d0"
}
```

[UDisks DBus API](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Encrypted.html) is guaranteed to be stable, the object path for the device will be always `/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/<name>`.

But you can always simply check whether the LUKS device has a child. The cleartext device will always be a child of the LUKS device so you can check either from `lsblk` or from sysfs.

Locked LUKS device:

```
$ ls /sys/block/sda/sda1/holders/
```

Unlocked LUKS device:

```
$ ls /sys/block/nvme0n1/nvme0n1p3/holders
dm-0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably not understanding the question but just look in `/dev/mapper/` to see if a mapping exists. It won't be there unless it's decrypted/unlocked.

To show active drive mapping drives:

```bsh
for file in $(readlink /dev/mapper/*); do echo $(ls -1 "/sys/block/${file##[./]}/slaves"); done
```